# Custom xmlWriter to skip a certain element?

Tags: c#, .net, xmldocument, xmlwriter

I am implementing a custom xmlwriter and I want to omit any elements with a particular name, like `<ABC>`.

How do I actually do that? I get a sense that I might need to overwrite the `WriteStartElement` method like this:

```
public override void WriteStartElement(string prefix, string localName, string ns)
{

    if (localName.Equals("ABC")) 
    {
        return;
    }
    base.WriteStartElement(prefix, localName, ns);
}
```

Do I also need to overwrite `WriteEndElement` method? How do I tell `WriteEndElement` method to skip writing the end `</ABC>` tag? There seems to be no reference of the `localName` in `WriteEndElement` method that I can check...?

Comment: It may help answering your question if you provide some context. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Why don't you try and see for yourself?

Comment: @Krumelur Because that tag carries useless content and will be confusing to show.

Comment: @BartoszKP I would. And I will definitely try out the WriteStartElement part. Just thought I should also overwrite WriteEndElement somehow to skip the ending tag but I am not sure how.

Comment: Do you need its children in the output?

Comment: You need to match WriteStart with a WriteEnd, meaning you need to count the number of start elements skipped

Comment: @Krumelur mmmm... That seems to be a bit more complex than I thought. This tag <ABC> won't have any nested child. Is there any good way to just skip it without having to count the numbers of start elements skipped?

Comment: There are lots of possible ways to address the basic need, making this question far too broad for StackOverflow. That said, I will recommend that your best bet would be to use LINQ and the System.Xml.Linq namespace objects. System.Xml.Linq provides an easy, LINQ-compatible API for manipulating the XML DOM, and of course LINQ itself provides great filtering and other query-like constructs.

Comment: Maybe you just should to remove nodes "ABC" from `XmlDocument`?

Comment: Do you want to eliminate just the `"ABC"` node and propagate all children to the parent node, or do you want to eliminate the `"ABC"` node and all children?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found this in some sample code I wrote previously.  It maintains a push-down stack to determine whether to write the element end, which is what you would need to do:

```
public class ElementSkippingXmlTextWriter : XmlWriterProxy
{
    readonly Stack<bool> stack = new Stack<bool>();
    readonly Func<string, string, int, bool> filter;
    readonly Func<string, string, int, string> nameEditor;
    readonly bool filterChildren;

    public ElementSkippingXmlTextWriter(XmlWriter writer, Func<string, string, int, bool> filter, bool filterChildren)
        : this(writer, filter, null, filterChildren)
    {
    }

    public ElementSkippingXmlTextWriter(XmlWriter writer, Func<string, string, int, bool> filter, Func<string, string, int, string> nameEditor, bool filterChildren)
        : base(writer)
    {
        this.filter = filter ?? delegate { return true; };
        this.nameEditor = nameEditor ?? delegate(string localName, string ns, int depth) { return localName; };
        this.filterChildren = filterChildren;
    }

    protected override bool IsSuspended
    {
        get
        {
            if (filterChildren)
            {
                if (!stack.All(b => b))
                    return true;
            }
            else
            {
                if (stack.Count > 0 && !stack.Peek())
                    return true;
            }

            return base.IsSuspended;
        }
    }

    public override void WriteStartElement(string prefix, string localName, string ns)
    {
        var write = filter(localName, ns, stack.Count);
        var newLocalName = nameEditor(localName, ns, stack.Count);
        if (write)
            base.WriteStartElement(prefix, newLocalName, ns);
        stack.Push(write);
    }

    public override void WriteEndElement()
    {
        if (stack.Pop())
            base.WriteEndElement();
    }
}

public class XmlWriterProxy : XmlWriter
{
    readonly XmlWriter baseWriter;

    public XmlWriterProxy(XmlWriter baseWriter)
    {
        if (baseWriter == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        this.baseWriter = baseWriter;
    }

    protected virtual bool IsSuspended { get { return false; } }

    public override WriteState WriteState { get { return baseWriter.WriteState; } }
    public override XmlWriterSettings Settings { get { return baseWriter.Settings; } }
    public override XmlSpace XmlSpace { get { return baseWriter.XmlSpace; } }
    public override string XmlLang { get { return baseWriter.XmlLang; } }

    public override void Close()
    {
        baseWriter.Close();
    }

    public override void Flush()
    {
        baseWriter.Flush();
    }

    public override string LookupPrefix(string ns)
    {
        return baseWriter.LookupPrefix(ns);
    }

    public override void WriteBase64(byte[] buffer, int index, int count)
    {
        if (IsSuspended)
            return;
        baseWriter.WriteBase64(buffer, index, count);
    }

    public override void WriteCData(string text)
    {
        if (IsSuspended)
            return;
        baseWriter.WriteCData(text);
    }

    public override void WriteCharEntity(char ch)
    {
        if (IsSuspended)
            return;
        baseWriter.WriteCharEntity(ch);
    }

    public override void WriteChars(char[] buffer, int index, int count)
    {
        if (IsSuspended)
            return;
        baseWriter.WriteChars(buffer, index, count);
    }

    public override void WriteComment(string text)
    {
        if (IsSuspended)
            return;
        baseWriter.WriteComment(text);
    }

    public override void WriteDocType(string name, string pubid, string sysid, string subset)
    {
        if (IsSuspended)
            return;
        baseWriter.WriteDocType(name, pubid, sysid, subset);
    }

    public override void WriteEndAttribute()
    {
        if (IsSuspended)
            return;
        baseWriter.WriteEndAttribute();
    }

    public override void WriteEndDocument()
    {
        if (IsSuspended)
            return;
        baseWriter.WriteEndDocument();
    }

    public override void WriteEndElement()
    {
        if (IsSuspended)
            return;
        baseWriter.WriteEndElement();
    }

    public override void WriteEntityRef(string name)
    {
        if (IsSuspended)
            return;
        baseWriter.WriteEntityRef(name);
    }

    public override void WriteFullEndElement()
    {
        if (IsSuspended)
            return;
        baseWriter.WriteFullEndElement();
    }

    public override void WriteProcessingInstruction(string name, string text)
    {
        if (IsSuspended)
            return;
        baseWriter.WriteProcessingInstruction(name, text);
    }

    public override void WriteRaw(string data)
    {
        if (IsSuspended)
            return;
        baseWriter.WriteRaw(data);
    }

    public override void WriteRaw(char[] buffer, int index, int count)
    {
        if (IsSuspended)
            return;
        baseWriter.WriteRaw(buffer, index, count);
    }

    public override void WriteStartAttribute(string prefix, string localName, string ns)
    {
        if (IsSuspended)
            return;
        baseWriter.WriteStartAttribute(prefix, localName, ns);
    }

    public override void WriteStartDocument(bool standalone)
    {
        baseWriter.WriteStartDocument(standalone);
    }

    public override void WriteStartDocument()
    {
        baseWriter.WriteStartDocument();
    }

    public override void WriteStartElement(string prefix, string localName, string ns)
    {
        if (IsSuspended)
            return;
        baseWriter.WriteStartElement(prefix, localName, ns);
    }

    public override void WriteString(string text)
    {
        if (IsSuspended)
            return;
        baseWriter.WriteString(text);
    }

    public override void WriteSurrogateCharEntity(char lowChar, char highChar)
    {
        if (IsSuspended)
            return;
        baseWriter.WriteSurrogateCharEntity(lowChar, highChar);
    }

    public override void WriteWhitespace(string ws)
    {
        if (IsSuspended)
            return;
        baseWriter.WriteWhitespace(ws);
    }
}
```

It wraps an `XmlWriter` you would create as usual with a call to [`XmlWriter.Create()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.create%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), and filters elements (and, optionally, children) for which the `filter` delegate returns `false`.

Note -- not fully tested.  [Async methods](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16641074) may need to be overridden as well.