# .net soap client serialization for empty tags

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization, soap

I'm working on an integration with an external service via the .NET.
I've got one problem related to the xml serialization process.

I have to pass empty tags as `<tag1></tag1>` but instead the SOAP client uses `<tag1 />`. Yes I know it's a valid xml but for some reasons the service seems to use it's own non standard xml parser which causing errors for my requests but no problem if I'm passing `<tag1></tag1>` manually.

Is there settings to change the default behavior of the SOAP client serializer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know anything about how the soap serializer works but I faced a similar problem when trying to ensure that a script tag was not a self closing for an xhtml output.  I was inspired a custom xml writer in answer from [dbc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3744182/dbc) in [Custom xmlWriter to skip a certain element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32149676/custom-xmlwriter-to-skip-a-certain-element) which set me off with the following....

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml;



public class XhtmlWriter : XmlWriterProxy
{
    readonly Stack<Node> stack = new Stack<Node>();
    readonly Func<string, string, int, bool> filter;
    readonly Func<string, string, int, string> nameEditor;
    readonly bool filterChildren;


    struct Node
    {
        public string prefix;
        public string localName;
        public string ns;
        public Behaviour filter;
    }

    [Flags]
    private enum Behaviour
    {
        StandardXml = 0,
        Exclude = 1,
        ExcludeSelfAndChildren = 2,
        FullClosingTag = 4,
    }

    private string[] selfClosingTags = { "area", "base", "br", "col", "command", "embed", "frame","hr","img","input","keygen","link","meta", "source","track","wbr",
            "path","circle","ellipse","line","polygon","rect","use"    // SVG

    };



    public XhtmlWriter(XmlWriter writer, Func<string, string, int, bool> filter, bool filterChildren)
        : this(writer, filter, null, filterChildren)
    {
    }

    public XhtmlWriter(XmlWriter writer, Func<string, string, int, bool> filter, Func<string, string, int, string> nameEditor, bool filterChildren)
        : base(writer)
    {
        this.filter = filter ?? delegate { return true; };
        this.nameEditor = nameEditor ?? delegate (string localName, string ns, int depth) { return localName; };
        this.filterChildren = filterChildren;
    }

    protected override bool IsSuspended
    {
        get
        {
            if (filterChildren)
            {
                if (stack.Count > 0 && stack.Peek().filter.HasFlag(Behaviour.Exclude))
                    return true;

                if (stack.Any(b => b.filter.HasFlag(Behaviour.ExcludeSelfAndChildren)))
                    return true;
            }

            return base.IsSuspended;
        }
    }


    public override void WriteStartElement(string prefix, string localName, string ns)
    {
        var write = filter(localName, ns, stack.Count);
        var newLocalName = nameEditor(localName, ns, stack.Count);
        if (write)
            base.WriteStartElement(prefix, newLocalName, ns);

        Node x;
        x.filter = write ? Behaviour.StandardXml : Behaviour.Exclude;
        x.localName = localName;
        x.prefix = prefix;
        x.ns = ns;


        if (!selfClosingTags.Any( t=> (t == localName)))
        {
            x.filter |= Behaviour.FullClosingTag;
        }


        stack.Push( x);
    }

    public override void WriteEndElement()
    {
        var node = stack.Pop();
        if (!node.filter.HasFlag(Behaviour.Exclude))
        {
            if (node.filter.HasFlag(Behaviour.FullClosingTag))
            {
                if (node.localName == "script")
                {
                    base.WriteString(" ");
                }
                base.WriteFullEndElement();
            }
            else
                base.WriteEndElement();
        }
    }





}






public class XmlWriterProxy : XmlWriter
{
    readonly XmlWriter baseWriter;

    public XmlWriterProxy(XmlWriter baseWriter)
    {
        if(baseWriter == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        this.baseWriter = baseWriter;
    }

    protected virtual bool IsSuspended { get { return false; } }

    public override void Close()
    {
        baseWriter.Close();
    }

    public override void Flush()
    {
        baseWriter.Flush();
    }

    public override string LookupPrefix(string ns)
    {
        return baseWriter.LookupPrefix(ns);
    }

    public override void WriteBase64(byte[] buffer, int index, int count)
    {
        if(IsSuspended)
            return;
        baseWriter.WriteBase64(buffer, index, count);
    }

    public override void WriteCData(string text)
    {
        if(IsSuspended)
            return;
        baseWriter.WriteCData(text);
    }

    public override void WriteCharEntity(char ch)
    {
        if(IsSuspended)
            return;
        baseWriter.WriteCharEntity(ch);
    }

    public override void WriteChars(char[] buffer, int index, int count)
    {
        if(IsSuspended)
            return;
        baseWriter.WriteChars(buffer, index, count);
    }

    public override void WriteComment(string text)
    {
        if(IsSuspended)
            return;
        baseWriter.WriteComment(text);
    }

    public override void WriteDocType(string name, string pubid, string sysid, string subset)
    {
        if(IsSuspended)
            return;
        baseWriter.WriteDocType(name, pubid, sysid, subset);
    }

    public override void WriteEndAttribute()
    {
        if(IsSuspended)
            return;
        baseWriter.WriteEndAttribute();
    }

    public override void WriteEndDocument()
    {
        if(IsSuspended)
            return;
        baseWriter.WriteEndDocument();
    }

    public override void WriteEndElement()
    {
        if(IsSuspended)
            return;
        baseWriter.WriteEndElement();
    }

    public override void WriteEntityRef(string name)
    {
        if(IsSuspended)
            return;
        baseWriter.WriteEntityRef(name);
    }

    public override void WriteFullEndElement()
    {
        if(IsSuspended)
            return;
        baseWriter.WriteFullEndElement();
    }

    public override void WriteProcessingInstruction(string name, string text)
    {
        if(IsSuspended)
            return;
        baseWriter.WriteProcessingInstruction(name, text);
    }

    public override void WriteRaw(string data)
    {
        if(IsSuspended)
            return;
        baseWriter.WriteRaw(data);
    }

    public override void WriteRaw(char[] buffer, int index, int count)
    {
        if(IsSuspended)
            return;
        baseWriter.WriteRaw(buffer, index, count);
    }

    public override void WriteStartAttribute(string prefix, string localName, string ns)
    {
        if(IsSuspended)
            return;
        baseWriter.WriteStartAttribute(prefix, localName, ns);
    }

    public override void WriteStartDocument(bool standalone)
    {
        baseWriter.WriteStartDocument(standalone);
    }

    public override void WriteStartDocument()
    {
        baseWriter.WriteStartDocument();
    }

    public override void WriteStartElement(string prefix, string localName, string ns)
    {
        if(IsSuspended)
            return;
        baseWriter.WriteStartElement(prefix, localName, ns);
    }

    public override WriteState WriteState
    {
        get { return baseWriter.WriteState; }
    }

    public override void WriteString(string text)
    {
        if(IsSuspended)
            return;

        baseWriter.WriteString(text);
    }

    public override void WriteSurrogateCharEntity(char lowChar, char highChar)
    {
        if(IsSuspended)
            return;
        baseWriter.WriteSurrogateCharEntity(lowChar, highChar);
    }

    public override void WriteWhitespace(string ws)
    {
        if(IsSuspended)
            return;
        baseWriter.WriteWhitespace(ws);
    }
}
```

It does more than you need but it may help set you off in the right direction.
Create is like so and then use it as your would use the standard xml writer

```
var xw = new XhtmlWriter(XmlWriter.Create( ... ), null, false);
xsl.Transform( ... , xw, ... );
```